# Search a column for one value and return the concatenated values from a second column on the corresponding rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column of technologies and a column of companies using those technologies.

I need to search the column of technologies (each cell contains multiple technologies) and return all the matched companies

Sample data:

```
Companies    Technologies                     
ACME         MailChimp, Dotmailer, Dynamics 
Phazer       Eloqua, Salesforce
Example      Dynamics, Dotmailer
Other        MailChimp, Eloqua
```

In this example, I want to search for companies using Dotmailer in the technologies column and return all the matching values (companies) from the companies column as a comma separated string .

So the return here should be:  `ACME,Example`

I've tried IF and VLOOKUP and couldn't get it to work.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question.  See [**the `VLOOKUP` Function**](https://support.office.com/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1).  Also see the [help/on-topic] for more information about what's on-topic on this site. If you still need help this is probably a better question for [SuperUser.com](http://superuser.com).

Comment: How do you need your results to be returned. Please give an example of the desired output as part of the much needed [mcve].

Comment: @ashleedawg I'm open to VBA macro responses, so feel this is an appropriate place to ask, the excel tag exists for a reason :). I will though check out superuser.com also, thanks. I have as mentioned in OP attempted VLOOKUP and did review those docs during that attempt.

Comment: @Luuklag I'm open to any option for how results are returned. Ideal would be a list of compaines seperated by coma, but not restricted by that as the only option.

Comment: @James - "They don't work" is awfully vague.  Please share the formula(s) you've tried, and a bit more information about what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your data is in column A,B.

Now lets make use of some helper cells:

Cell F1 will be the cell where you enter your search criteria.

Column C will be used to indicate matches, we find and display them with the following formula in C2 and down: `=IF(IFERROR(Find($F$1,B2),"")<>"";A2)`

Unfortunately using concatenate with empty cells isn't working, so we need helper column D as well. In column D we use the following formula to build one string from all matches found in column C. Starting in D2: `=IF(C2<>"";C2;"")` And in D3: `=IF(D2<>"";IF(C3<>"";D2&","&C3;D2);IF(C3<>"";C3;""))` which we drag down.

Then Cell F2 will return the result by inserting `=INDIRECT("D"&COUNTA(D:D))`

Comment: This has worked. Thank you for the assistance and for detailing why this has worked. I believe this will help me and others solve other challenges in the future.

Comment: Just happy to help